# jQuery scrollTo with sliding scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollbar, scrollto

I'm using the scrollTo plugin for a horizontal website and it works fine. I have a list of links on the main section and I can also easily move among them one at a time, back and forth.  For the plugin to work I have to use the `overflow:hidden` property, however I want to give users the choice to slide the scrollbar if they prefer it.  So I found the LocalScroll plugin and with a bit of code (written by someone else, I just copied it as is) I now have the scrollbar sliding along each section of the site.

The problem is that the anchors I use to move one section back and forward stopped working, so I have to keep going back to the front page to click on whatever section I want to see.  It might be better explained with [this example](http://bellotaestudio.com/tmp/test.html).  Click on any link to go to a specific section, and within that section the 'back' and 'forth' links don't work.  You have to click the logo (well, the space where it should be) to the left to go back to the main section.

I've seen other examples of horizontal websites and I noticed that the ones with the sliding scrollbar as I need it only have a couple of main links and they're fixed-positioned, so I'm wondering if it's possible to make it work the way I have it.

In the example, the custom.js file is the one that works with `overflow:hidden`, and the test.js file has the additional plugin/code I added.

As always I'd appreciate very much any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With scrollTo I was using jQuery classes to move from one section to another, so I just removed those clases and used the sections id's in the anchor elements.  It now works as I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help: i actually made this for dynamic menu in wordpress
you can see working version of this here:
http://loco.karolwasik.pl/ (script.js)

```
$('#menu a').bind('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#subpanel-maska').scrollTo('#panel-'+$(e.target).attr('title'), 300, {easing: 'easeOutCirc'})
}
```

btw. your code in this custom is kinda messy, you should minimize it or something (i know mine is too ;) )

Comment: It didn't work but thanks.  By the way, besides minimize what else do you think could be improved in my code?

Comment: well i'm not a pro but try to join events in .bind in something like this:   
    `.bind('mouseup mousedown click' function(e){ 
    if(e.type==='mousedown'){ ... }
 })`

secondly - write one function goto and make it dynamic - for example get parameter _where to go_ from attr('href') or title or even id.

it will shorten your code up to 15% :D

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I'll take any advice I get to improve my coding skills :)